# How to keep `X` and `Q` styles at the same time in `tabularray`?

Tags: tabularray

`tabularray` is quite useful as I need to do these things:

1. Keep the table as wide as `\textwidth`
2. I need to insert `note{}` in the caption of the table
3. The head of the table are two many characters, so they are divided into several lines in one cell. In this case, I need to keep short heads to be the middle of the cell of the table
4. Keep the number decimal aligned

As I know:

- To achieve `1`, I can use `tblr` or `talltblr` with `X` format
- To achieve `2`, I need use `talltblr`
- To achieve `4`, I can use `talltblr` with `X` and `si={}`

But, how can I achieve `3` by `talltblr`? If we can merge `Q` format into `talltblr`, these four functions could be achieved at the same time.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{romannum}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{talltblr}
    [caption={Main component geographic information table\TblrNote{1}},
     label={tab:Main component geographic information table},
     note{1}={The data is obtained through satellite maps, and there are certain errors},
     note{2}={The latitude and longitude of the surface is the latitude and longitude of its centroid. There is a certain error in the measurement of latitude and longitude, for reference},
     note{3}={This length is the length in our study area}
    ]
    {colspec={
              X[1.5,r] X[1.3,c] X[1.3,c] X[c,si={table-format=4.2},0.8] X[c,si={table-format=4.2},0.8] X[c,si={table-format=1.2},0.8]
              } 
    }
    \toprule
      name  & latitude\TblrNote{2} & longitude &{gggggg\unit{\m}}  & gggggg\unit{\m} \TblrNote{3} &{{{area total\unit{\km\squared}}}}\\
    
         \midrule
      DongLake      &\ang{30;33;29.52}N &\ang{114;22;47.55}E &             &         & 12.74 \\
      dongtinglake     &\ang{30;33;12.71}N &\ang{114;20;46.87}E &         &         &0.12 \\
      great river      &\ang{30;33;33.66}N &\ang[minimum-integer-digits=2]{114;20;09.29}E & 1682.88&         &        \\
     bigbig lake      &\ang[minimum-integer-digits=2]{30;34;06.02}N &\ang{114;19;45.86}E &         &         & 2.74    \\
     inside the gate   &\ang{30;33;54.85}N &\ang{114;18;35.99}E &         &         & 0.06  \\
      new ditches     &\ang{30;35;33.19}N &\ang[minimum-integer-digits=2]{114;23;02.77}E & 977    &         &         \\
      west part of new gate   &\ang{30;35;26.31}N &\ang{114;21;43.67}E & 5213.77 &         &         \\
     luoai port   &\ang[minimum-integer-digits=2]{30;37;08.49}N &\ang{114;21;27.93}E & 3770.58 &         &         \\
qingling port     &\ang[minimum-integer-digits=2]{30;39;02.32}N &\ang{114;24;30.27}E &         &         & 0.13   \\
      from port to lake &\ang[minimum-integer-digits=2]{30;37;03.06}N &\ang{114;24;22.99}E & 345.15 &         &        \\
    east part of the gate   &\ang[minimum-integer-digits=2]{30;38;05.41}N &\ang{114;24;27.64}E &2926.08 &         &         \\
   Yangzi river     &\ang{30;37;43.29}N &\ang{114;20;58.87}E &         &         &         \\
      east part of the lake   &\ang{30;35;55.14}N &\ang{114;23;14.49}E & 1090.45 &         &         \\
      donghu port     &\ang{30;35;37.38}N &\ang{114;23;45.81}E & 7332.3 & \num{4614.19} &         \\
   west section of qingqing   &\ang[minimum-integer-digits=2]{30;38;01.20}N &\ang{114;24;11.10}E & 3449.86 &         &         \\
    new road   drainage station &\ang{30;33;55.17}N &\ang{114;18;48.14}E &         &         &         \\
nanjing drainage station  &\ang{30;33;52.23}N &\ang{114;18;29.72}E &         &         &         \\
      beijing pumping station   &\ang{30;37;22.34}N &\ang[minimum-integer-digits=2]{114;21;01.01}E &         &         &         \\
      guilin road gata   &\ang{30;37;19.42}N &\ang{114;20;57.23}E &         &         &       \\
      the last gate     &\ang{30;39;16.08}N &\ang{114;24;31.97}E &         &         &     \\     
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

How to make this table to achieve the four requests?
[image]

Another question: why can't I replace `gggggg` with `Length`? When I did this, there is error: `Package siunitx Error: Invalid number 'e'.`

Comment: All this (except Q column) contain my answer on your previous question. Beside this, all this is thoroughly described with many examples in the package documentation (it is part of its installation, available is also on CTAN).

Comment: @Zarko Hello, I checked the file: `https://texdoc.org/serve/tabularray/0`. I didn't find a way to merge `Q`, `X` and `si` into `talltablr`. At this time, I know how to merge `X` and `si` into `talltablr` from your previous answer. `Q` can adjust columns and rows style.

Comment: An `X` column is just `Q[co=1]`...

Comment: @PaulGaborit May you tell me the reason?

Comment: In `tabularray.sty`, you find the definition of `X`: `\NewColumnRowType{X}[1][]{Q[co=1,#1] }`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit I never make a new command before. What does this mean and how to use it?

Comment: I have package documentation ... I don't see any sense to write you general answer by copying text from it to an answer. Please provide an example, what you like to achieve. For example `colspec = {r Q[l,m] X[1,h,j] X[2,h,j] Q[l,m]}` should works out of the box. Table will has `\textwidth` width due to used `X` columns. For more, let me repeat myself, please provide an MWE, that we can see, what you like to have.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for your reminder. I modified my post. If you have time, please guide me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:**
ups, I didn't upload the last version of code and image. Corrected now. So4ry for noise ...

As starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx} % libraries loads packages of the same names

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \sisetup{minimum-integer-digits=2}
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Main component geographic information table},
  label = {tab:Main component geographic information table},
remark{Note} = {The data are obtained through satellite maps, and there are certain errors},
     note{1} = {The latitude and longitude of the surface is the latitude and longitude of its centroid. There is a certain error in the measurement of latitude and longitude, for reference},
     note{2} = {This length is the length in our study area},
     note{3} = {Total area}
                ]{colsep = 3pt,
                  colspec = {@{} X[2,l, m, font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont] r r
                            *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=4.2}]}
                                 X[c, si={table-format=2.2,
                                          minimum-integer-digits=1}]
                            @{}},
                   row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries, c, m}
    }
    \toprule
name        & latitude\TblrNote{1} 
                & longitude
                     & {{{gggggg \unit{\metre}}}}
                        & {{{gggggg\TblrNote{2} \unit{\metre}}}}
                            & {{{area\TblrNote{3} \unit{\km\squared}}}}\\

    \midrule
Dong Lake    & \ang{30;33;29.52}N 
                & \ang{114;22;47.55}E 
                    &   &   & 12.74         \\
Dongting Lake     
            & \ang{30;33;12.71}N 
                &\ang{114;20;46.87}E 
                    &   &   & 0.12          \\
Great river & \ang{30;33;33.66}N
                & \ang{114;20;09.29}E  
                    & 1682.88
                        &   &               \\
Big lake    & \ang{30;34;06.02}N        
                & \ang{114;19;45.86}E 
                    &   &   & 2.74          \\
inside the gate   
            & \ang{30;33;54.85}N 
                & \ang{114;18;35.99}E 
                    &   &   & 2.74          \\
new ditches & \ang{30;35;33.19}N    
                &\ang{114;23;02.77}E 
                    & 977    
                        &   &               \\
west part of new gate   
            & \ang{30;35;26.31}N 
                & \ang{114;21;43.67}E 
                    & 5213.77 
                        &   &               \\
Luoai port  & \ang{30;37;08.49}N    
                &\ang{114;21;27.93}E 
                    & 3770.58 
                        &   &               \\
qingling port     
            & \ang{30;39;02.32}N    
                &\ang{114;24;30.27}E 
                    &   &   & 0.13          \\
from port to lake 
            & \ang{30;37;03.06}N    
                & \ang{114;24;22.99}E 
                    & 345.15 
                        &   &               \\
east part of the gate   
            & \ang{30;38;05.41}N   
                & \ang{114;24;27.64}E 
                    & 2926.08 
                        &   &               \\
Yangzi river     
            & \ang{30;37;43.29}N 
                & \ang{114;20;58.87}E 
                    &   &   &               \\
east part of the lake   
            & \ang{30;35;55.14}N 
                & \ang{114;23;14.49}E 
                    & 1090.45 
                        &   &               \\
Donghu port & \ang{30;35;37.38}N 
                & \ang{114;23;45.81}E 
                    & 7332.3 
                        & 4614.19
                            &               \\
west section of qingqing   
            & \ang{30;38;01.20}N   
                & \ang{114;24;11.10}E
                    & 3449.86
                        &   &               \\
new road  drainage station 
            & \ang{30;33;55.17}N 
                &\ang{114;18;48.14}E 
                    &   &   &               \\
nanjing drainage station  
            & \ang{30;33;52.23}N 
                & \ang{114;18;29.72}E 
                    &   &   &               \\
Beijing pumping station   
            & \ang{30;37;22.34}N 
                &\ang{114;21;01.01}E    
                    &   &   &               \\
Guilin road gata   
            & \ang{30;37;19.42}N 
                &\ang{114;20;57.23}E 
                    &   &   &               \\
the last gate     
            & \ang{30;39;16.08}N 
                & \ang{114;24;31.97}E 
                    &   &   &               \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Notes:**
You really read (again and again) package documentation. Not just read but also experimenting with different settings for column formatting. My experiences show me, that the best metod of learning is *learning-by-doing*. At start is a bit time consuming, but you will quite soon figured out philosophy of `tabularray` syntax.

- Meaning of options `c` (center), `l` (left), `r` (right) and `m` (middle), `t` (top) `b` (bottom, last three are defined in the `array` package) is the same as at classic tables. - Beside mentioned options, `tabularray` introduce three more options: `h` (head, at top of cell), `f` (foot, at bottom of cell) and `j` (justified).
- This options can be used stand alone or as attributes of `X` or `Q` columns types. For example:

  - `X[c]`  has width, which is calculated by LaTeX and column content is horizontal
  - `X[2,l] has twice of width, which is calculated by LaTeX and left aligned column content
  - `Q[c, 2cm]` or `Q[c, wd=2cm]` define column with 2cm width and horizonal centered content
  - `X[j]` has justified text, which is hyphenated when needed
  - column `c` behave the same as at "classic" tables width of column is equal to the width of longest content in cells and is horizontal centered (similarly is for other options)
- At `S` columns (define as `S` column or for example `Q[c, si]`, where formatting can be defined by `\sisetup` outside of table, see `siunitx` documentation) the no number content of such cel had to be according `siunitx` package in classic tables enclosed in pair of curly braces:

  - by this is interrupted `table-format` settings,
  - disabled wrong interpretation of content meaning (bear in mind, that `siunitx` use some letters for designate numbers, for example `10e5` mean `10 x 10^5`!
- The `tabularray` due to different table processing (using `l3exp`) require to add two more curly braces pairs (that `siunitx` requirement works in all circumstances).
- The `tabularray` package enables formatting rows to. For examples:

  - with `row{1} = {font=\bfseries}` prescribe boldface text in all row cells in the first row,
  - with `row{Z} = {font=\scfaily, c}` prescribe small caps font and centering of contents in the last row in table
- etc.,

**Addendum:**
you may liked table formatting, which groups rows, for example with three of them and insert some additional vertical space between them. For this add to preamble

```
  \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachthree}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {5}{3}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

and to table preamble:

```
                   row{eachthree} = {abovesep=2ex},
```

Considering this additions, table will los as follow:

[image]

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply. What's the meaning of `2` in `X[2,l, m, font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont]`?

Comment: Which codes made the units of columns 4, 5 and 6 not bold and become the second row? Can't the  `font ` modifie the `siunitx`? Am I right?

Comment: Why will changing `{{{gggggg \unit{\metre}}}}` to `{{{ gggggg\unit{\metre}}}}`  make it one line? What's the meaning of `blank` in the `{{{gggggg \unit{\metre}}}}` ?

Comment: Please, red package documentation. Answers on all your question you will find in it. :-). `X[2, ...]` means that column width is 2 x width column if it will be just `X[...]`. Column headers should not be wider than column width, so it is advisable to enable that it can be split in two (or more) lines when needed. In addition, the meaning of the text becomes meaningful. You can set all table to smaller font if you put `\small` directive after `\begin{table}`.

Comment: I can't understand the package documentation very well. Maybe for my poor English or for my poor LaTeX skill. Is the `blank` advisable to enable it can be split into two lines? Why didn't you use `c c` in  `X[2,l, m, font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont] r r`? I tested `c c` and it is not right. But I don't know the reason. Why did the `r r` make blank between columns?

Comment: Why are there error when changing `{{{gggggg \unit{\metre}}}}` to `Length \unit{\metre}`?

Comment: Because not number cell content had to be enclosed with three curly braces pairs (you not believe documentation nor my comments at your previous question :-( )

Comment: Okay. I know now. Why didn't you use `c c` in `X[2,l, m, font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont] r r`? I tested `X[2,l, m, font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont] c c` and it is not right. But I don't know the reason. Why did the `r r` make blank between columns?

Comment: @Y.zeng, see notes to answer. `r` column type doesn't make anything blank. If some cell is empty, than you not write any content in it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patient explanation. I understand 2/3. In the future, I will read the document again and again with doing it at the same time.  Have a nice day ahead！

Comment: Hello, does `colsep = 3pt` set each default column width to 3pt? How should I know how many "pts" of `\textwitdth`?

Comment: @Y.zeng,  of `colsep`  (it is equivalent to `\tabcolsep` in classic tables) is minimal  horizontal distance between cell content and cell border.  It default value is 6 pt (pints).

Comment: Why did you set this `colsep = 3pt`?

Comment: @Y.zeng, remove it and than see the difference :-). That can be put wider text into cells.

Comment: Why didn't set it to 0? I removed it and found the fourth column is under below others. It is a little weird.

Comment: @Y.zeng, that is matter of personal preference (opinion based).

Comment: I removed `colsep = 3pt` and found the fourth column is below others. Why?